Does a readied action have to be an action?
Like, if I'm near a cliff about to be knocked down the cliff, but I have wings, can I hold my action to catch myself with my wings?

Is your question about held action in general, or specific for the flying? Those are two very different questions.

I suggest you use the correct terminology.  Go and look into the Basic Rules. They are free.  You are probably referring to Ready An Action.  See Chapter 9.

The text is ambiguous.

First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

It says "the action" which can either imply one of the specific Actions in Combat, or the generalized definition of an act.
It would be reasonable to allow any act to be taken (within reason) rather than one of the specific Actions. Examples could include shouting or letting go of a rope as a held action, neither of which are capital "A" Actions.
For your specific scenario, as long as you can hover or you aren't under one of the specific effects identified in the PHB that causes you to fall in flight (prone, speed 0, oherwise can't move), you don't even need to ready an action to avoid falling. Your fly speed will keep you afloat automatically.
Flying creatures can "hover"
Flying creatures can stay in the air and "hover" in the technical sense of the word regardless of whether they have the "hover" tag. By that I mean they can stay in the air and remain in one spot. Nothing in the rules regarding flying movement require a flying creature remains in motion. The rules from the PHB read:

Flying creatures enjoy many benefits of mobility, but they must also deal with the danger of falling. If a flying creature is knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls, unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as by the fly spell.

The rules specify exactly when a flying creature may fall. Not being in continuous movement is not one of them. So a flying creature can fly into a space in the air and remain there for as long as they want. Otherwise, the rules would have said something to the effect of "a flying creature must remain moving to stay flying."
The benefit of the actual "hover" tag next to some monsters with a flying speed is that they won't fall from the sky if under one of the effects that normally end flight (prone, speed 0, otherwise can't move).

You don't need to have movement remaining, just that your speed is not 0.

Can you back up that a fly speed keeps you afloat automatically?

@justhalf thanks for the clarification, that's what I meant. Edited to correct.

@senmurv Added justification for flying creatures staying afloat.

If you have flying speed (which I assume your character has given the wings), you don't fall when knocked off a cliff, unless you are prone, or your speed is 0 or otherwise loses your ability to move (unless you can hover), as per the falling rules quoted below:

A flying creature in flight falls if it is knocked prone, if its speed is reduced to 0 feet, or if it otherwise loses the ability to move, unless it can hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as the fly spell.

Basic Rules (2014), Chapter 9: Combat
I assume the normal reading of above that unless one fulfills the conditions for falling specified there, you do not fall.

So just take my turn as normal and let them try to knock me off since I'm fine whether they succeed or not?

@Tasi Unless your character believes the enemy can make them prone or restrained, a flying creature usually does not fear height.

If the creature is standing on the ground, such that it makes any sense to be knocked off a cliff in the first place, then I don't think it is reasonable to interpret them as being "in flight".  That is a requirement for the quoted rule to apply to the situation, or else that free fall automatically converts to being "in flight" for creatures with a flying speed (subject to the given limitations).  The OP seems to be asking exactly about transitioning to "in flight" from not.

There's some ambiguity in "a flying creature" - does it mean a creature capable of flight, or one that is currently flying?

There are no “held” actions
D&D 5e has the Ready Action, which is what I presume you mean.

First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

So, an action is:

When you take your action on your turn, you can take one of the actions presented here, an action you gained from your class or a special feature, or an action that you improvise.

So, an action is almost anything you can imagine; you are not limited to any particular list.
However, …
Movement isn’t an action
“[C]atch myself with my wings” sounds like movement to me. But, the good news is that the Ready action explicitly allows you to ready an action or move up to your speed.
Creatures with a flying speed usually don’t fall

If a flying creature is knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls, unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as by the fly spell.

So, if you get knocked off the cliff, unless you are also prone, have a speed of 0, or are “otherwise deprived of the ability to move”, you aren’t going to fall. The “catch myself with my wings” thing is automatic.
However, if you are prone, the Ready action paired with movement will allow you to stand up using half your speed. It probably isn’t going to help if you “have a speed of 0, or are “otherwise deprived of the ability to move”.

It seems like there must be a distinction between a "flying creature" as one that is currently flying on one hand, and as one who is capable of flight on the other.  Surely a creature that ordinarily has a flying speed but is standing on the ground does not fall on account of being deprived of the ability to move? But then, the question is about when and how a creature with a flying speed goes from not-flying to flying.
